# How to execute .py file and write the output including plots to .html file

Tags: python, html, output, ipython

In Spyder, I can run a .py file and get/see the output including print statements and plots in the ipython console. Then, I can right-click on the ipython console and save the whole things as .html file.

Is there a way to do the same thing with a one liner? Like from command line or from another .py file?

Comment: Did you try `%logstart -o` command in IPython console ?
It will start saving all your console log in a file named `ipthon_log.py` in your current running directory.

Comment: totally off the track comment, have you tried plotly ? html graph made me think in that direction, though I do not know your requirements at all :)

Comment: Thanks, @Haramoz. Yes, I am aware of it but have not used it. As I've said, I like to save the output of .py file including plots to an html file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your plots/charts also to be saved in your html but unfortunately there is no straightforward solutions. Also, there is no commands in IPython console for that. You have to do manually `Ctrl + S` or `Right Click ==> Save as HTML/XML` or you can simulate clicking `Ctrl + S` using some script.

But, if you want to save text logs only(without plots)

Try command `%logstart testingToLog.html` in your IPython console of spyder to redirect your logging onto a file named `testingToLog.html` or of any extension.
Here is the documentation for [%logstart](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-logstart)
Here is a snapshot: 
[image]

Now, obvious question is, how would you stop the logging which you started.
This can be done using command `%logstop` in same IPython console.
Also, you can pass `%logstate` command to Print the status of logging system.

Comment: Thanks. I tested this, and it works for string outputs. (It saves them a bit odd as it saves all the outputs without using a carrier return.) But I am interested in capturing the plots too.